# Calculating angles and distances

Tags: c++, performance, computational-geometry

I am running a simulation with 250 interacting agents and have a few functions that are called over and over again. Even with precomputing all distances between agents before the N<sup>2</sup> (250x250) interaction loop, my simulation is still very slow. Are there any C++ optimization tricks that I could use to speed these up?

This is the most-used function in my simulation. It calculates the distance<sup>2</sup> between two agents in a continuous space. I have a feeling there isn't much that can be done to further optimize this, but you guys have surprised me with some tricks before:

```
double tGame::calcDistanceSquared(double fromX, double fromY, double toX, double toY)
{
    double diffX = fromX - toX;
    double diffY = fromY - toY;

    return ( diffX * diffX ) + ( diffY * diffY );
}
```

Here's another expensive function in my simulation. It calculates the angle from one agent to another agent relative to the 'from' agent's heading. As you can see, I already did a little precomputing with the `atan2()` function (and that DOES speed things up a bit, despite what I've read in other posts).

```
double tGame::calcAngle(double fromX, double fromY, double fromAngle, double toX, double toY)
{
    double Ux = 0.0, Uy = 0.0, Vx = 0.0, Vy = 0.0;

    Ux = (toX - fromX);
    Uy = (toY - fromY);

    Vx = cosLookup[(int)fromAngle];
    Vy = sinLookup[(int)fromAngle];

    int firstTerm = (int)((Ux * Vy) - (Uy * Vx));
    int secondTerm = (int)((Ux * Vx) + (Uy * Vy));

    if (fabs(firstTerm) < 1000 && fabs(secondTerm) < 1000)
    {
        return atan2Lookup[firstTerm + 1000][secondTerm + 1000];
    }

    else
    {
        return atan2(firstTerm, secondTerm) * 180.0 / cPI;
    }
}
```

Finally, here's the monster function that uses the `calcDistanceSquared()` function so much. This is run every simulation time step, and there's 2,000 time steps per simulation (and MANY simulations). The most expensive part is the `calcDistanceSquared()` in the N<sup>2</sup> loop.

```
void tGame::recalcPredAndPreyDistTable(double preyX[], double preyY[], bool preyDead[],
                                       double predX, double predY,
                                       double predDists[250], double preyDists[250][250])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 250; ++i)
    {
        if (!preyDead[i])
        {
            predDists[i] = calcDistanceSquared(predX, predY, preyX[i], preyY[i]);
            preyDists[i][i] = 0.0;

            for (int j = i + 1; j < 250; ++j)
            {
                if (!preyDead[j])
                {
                    preyDists[i][j] = preyDists[j][i] = calcDistanceSquared(preyX[i], preyY[i], preyX[j], preyY[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a space partitioning algorithm to avoid the N^2 loop.

Comment: Just my 2 cents: is it *really* necessary for each of the 250 agents to interact with *all* other 249? For swarm AI, usually only the *n* nearest are used, which basically makes the `N^2` a `N`.

Comment: @Constantinius I am simulating a retina for each prey, thus I have to *at least* know if each prey is within a visible range.

Comment: @GManNickG Excuse my ignorance (I've never used a space partitioning algorithm before), but would it take a large overhaul to implement a space partitioning algorithm in a continuous space like this?

Comment: @RandyOlson: Large overhaul or not, you have to do it. Speed up and optimization is rarely about the little nanosecond improvements you might spend (waste) time finding. It's about structuring your data efficiently for your use. Anything beyond the smallest toy games need to organize their entities in space.

Comment: Is it possible there are some simulations where the behavior of the agents doesn't have to be recalculated every step? In other words, for some objects in your graph, there are groups of time steps that can be calculated either based on a single polynomial, or that are only affected by a small set of neighboring objects. That's probably what GMan means by space partitioning.

Comment: @GManNickG Any recommended tutorials for converting a continuous space into a partitioned space?

Comment: @AustinMullins To be honest: I'm not sure. I would imagine there are time steps that I am recalculating the distance between certain agents when I really don't need to (e.g., because they haven't moved, or are off by themselves somewhere), but I haven't been able to come up with any tricks that don't end up being even more expensive than just calculating the distance.

Comment: What are you using the distances for?  If you're only looking at the smallest few, there will be some computational geometry tricks that will help you.  If you're doing gravity or something, you can use the fast multipole method.

Comment: @tmyklebu I am simulating a retina for each agent, thus I have to at least know if each agent is within a visible range.

Comment: Instead of recalculating all the distances, can you calculate only the few that have moved.  Perhaps change the design so that when an entity moves, it notifies your object?  See Publisher / Subscriber Design.

Comment: Try Loop Unrolling (search the web or SO).

Comment: @RandyOlson Look into using an octree.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Loop unrolling is unlikely to help here, as the problem is with the algorithm, not the implementation or the limits of C's assertions on its pointers.

Answer (score 3):

It looks good to me. I would change

```
    if (!preyDead[i])
    {
```

To

```
    if (preyDead[i])
            continue;
```

Just so its less nested. Same with preyDead[j]. But everything looks fine to me.
A tip I once saw on SO is, if your list order doesn't matter you can sort the preyDead so all the dead would be at the beginning or end and that will help branch prediction. However thats assuming its not really expensive to sort it and that its a very erratic bool and it isnt true/false 90% of the time already.

Thats a uber optimize that may not help, it shouldn't be done less you really really want to

Answer (score 1):

It is being said that compilers can vectorize stuff better if there are no ifs in loops. So, in that spirit, try to remove the if from the inner loop of `recalcPredAndPreyDistTable()` to see if it does not vectorize better and thus generate better code and thus is not a performance win despite the recomputation of distances between the dead prey.

Second thought, if you have a compiler that supports OpenMP, try to parallelize the outer loop, like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i = 0; i < 250; ++i)
    {
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you will not get maximum benefits from code changes, but see my answer here:
[Optimization Coding Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074099/coding-practices-which-enable-the-compiler-optimizer-to-make-a-faster-program/2075264#2075264)

One issue that is screaming out is why are you making so many iterations?
For example, do *all* the positions need to be recalculated?

Can you cache the calculations?
You only need to perform the calculations if something moves.  You can quickly detect if something moves by comparing the coordinates (don't need to calculate distances here).

Another observation is that you are currently *polling*, that is, looping until something moves.  You may want to change your paradigm to event driven:  when something changes, it sends out a message or notification.  With the Event Driven paradigm, your reduce a lot of computation for things that don't change.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly whatever you try to achieve with "fromAngle" and atan2, can be accomplished with pure vector math.

Re-arrange the matrix (with extra level of indirection in other parts of the code) so that the prayDead[i]==true are in the beginning of the array (and prayDead[i]==false) are at the end.

It does not only reduce branch prediction, but decreases from N*N to (N-n)*(N-n).

Also it may not be optimal to try to reduce the operations from N*N to N*N/2 by computing an upper triangle. It's better to make a simple loop that the compiler can parallelize (that's 4x gain compared to max 2x gain from reducing the symmetry.)

Further, it's often better to split 256x256 operations to 32x32 x 8x8 operations or so. Then each block will benefit from the array being in cache -- however in this case it may again be beneficial to permute upper triangle blocks:

```
a b c <-- here the diagonal blocks (a,d,f) are calculated as usual
B d e     but B,C,E can be calculated by rotating the results of (b,c,e)
C E f
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is possible - try to rewrite methods header like this.
Once I get valuable speed-up. This is because you have no need to copy arrays, you can give to your method only addresses.

```
void tGame::recalcPredAndPreyDistTable(double &preyX[], double &preyY[], bool &preyDead[],
                                           double predX, double predY,
                                           double &predDists[250], double &preyDists[250][250])
```

**EDIT:** will this work?

```
void tGame::recalcPredAndPreyDistTable(double *preyX, double *preyY, bool *preyDead,
                                           double predX, double predY,
                                           double *predDists, double **preyDists)
```

Comment: If I remember right, arrays are passed by reference by default in C++.

Comment: Randy is kind of correct. C arrays are just pointers, no more, no less... So, this adds nothing.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: Please, do **not** maintain the false assertion that arrays are pointers alive!!! Arrays are **not** pointers, they *decay* into pointers easily, but they are **not** pointers.

Comment: @cupidon4uk: The code in your answer will not compile, `double &preyX[]` means *array of unknown number of references to `double`* which is not legal in C++. Even if you added parenthesis as in `double (&preyX)[]` meaning *reference to an array...* it would still not compile as you cannot have a reference to an array of an unknown number of elements.

Comment: @dribeas Really? C style arrays are pretty much just pointers once you pass then to another function. Of course, in a function they reserve space on the stack. Now, in C++, you shouldn't use C arrays any more. Use std::array if you can, otherwise tr1 or boost. Pass them by const reference and all is good with the world. Furthermore, if you want to return an array, just return an array. Compilers will optimise out the copy.